# Listar livros mais emprestados

Tags: sqlite

Gostaria de listar os livro por ordem de mais emprestados, mas nãotem nenhum livro que foi emprestado então não mostra nenhum. Gostaria que mostrasse por ordem mas mesmo que o livro não tenha sido emprestado nenhuma vez ele tem que estar listado.

```
SELECT Livros.Nome, COUNT(Emprestimo.Livro_IDLivro) FROM Livros 
INNER JOIN Emprestimo ON Livros.IDLivro = Emprestimo.Livro_IDLivro 
ORDER BY COUNT(Emprestimo.Livro_IDLivro) ASC;
```

Comment: José, seu problema é muito simples. Sugiro que leia o post para entender a diferença entre o `INNER` e o `LEFT`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para listar todos os livros voce precisa utilizar o `LEFT JOIN` ao inves do `INNER JOIN`, pois o `LEFT` te trará todos registros da tabela que está à esquerda (primeira tabela).

A para mostrar do que tem mais para o que tem menos, você precisa usar o `DESC` no seu `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT Livros.Nome, COUNT(Emprestimo.Livro_IDLivro) FROM Livros 
LEFT JOIN Emprestimo ON Livros.IDLivro = Emprestimo.Livro_IDLivro 
ORDER BY COUNT(Emprestimo.Livro_IDLivro) DESC;
```